# Do old trophies carry over to new games?

Tags: achievements, ps3, lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

If you start a new game of Lego Harry Potter Years 1-4 will you keep the trophies you have earned on the first play through and only need to achieve the ones the won't unlock? Animagus is the only trophy that won't unlock for me.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the PS3 version? I don't know for sure, but pretty sure you can't unlock a trophy twice, so yes, you'd be left with collecting just the last one I believe.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. Trophies can't be unearned. This is one of the most basic charasteristics of trophies. This applies to every game that has trophies. What drives you to think this game somehow is different?

Comment: If, however, you were wondering whether starting a new playthrough would reset the *progress* towards a trophy, then the answer is yes for this game.

Answer (score 2):

If you begin a new game, you **will** retain all previously collected trophies. In your case, Animagus will still be the only locked trophy.

Often, you'll find mutually exclusive trophies i.e. two you can't get in the same play through. An example of this would be Dishonoured's no-kill achievement and the kill-using-all-gadgets achievement.

Additionally, as per Robotnik's comment, you will often only get one opportunity to achieve a trophy, meaning you might need to make multiple playthroughs to try and get them.

Comment: Adding to this, a lot of games have trophies that can only be earned once in a playthrough, forcing you to play the game again in order to try and achieve them

Comment: Don't you mean, "locked trophy"?  Sounds weird if the only unlocked trophy is the one he needs.

Comment: @fbueckert no idea what you mean... >.>

Answer (score 0):

Trophies are linked to your PSN account. Provided that you're using the same PSN account when you start a new game, then they will carry over. Many games have trophies that you can't get unless you play them more than once and make different choices.